# Need help making final touches to my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm writing a coffee machine code and I'm almost done with it except there is an aspect I don't really know how to fix.

Here is the code:

```
from data import resources
from data import MENU


penny = 0.01
nickle = 0.05
dime = 0.1
quarter = 0.25
coffee_machine_on = True

espresso_cost = MENU["espresso"]["cost"]
latte_cost = MENU["latte"]["cost"]
cappuccino_cost = MENU["cappuccino"]["cost"]


def resource_deduction():
    """
    Deducts the amount of resources each coffee type uses from the coffee machine 
    """
    if choice == "espresso":
        if resources["water"] >= MENU["espresso"]["ingredients"]["water"]:
            resources["water"] = resources["water"] - MENU["espresso"]["ingredients"]["water"]
        else:
            return "Sorry there is no enough water"
        if resources["coffee"] >= MENU["espresso"]["ingredients"]["coffee"]:
            resources["coffee"] = resources["coffee"] - MENU["espresso"]["ingredients"]["coffee"]
        else:
            return "Sorry there is no enough coffee"
    elif choice == "latte":
        if resources["water"] >= MENU["latte"]["ingredients"]["water"]:
            resources["water"] = resources["water"] - MENU["latte"]["ingredients"]["water"]
        else:
            return "Sorry there is no enough water"

        if resources["milk"] >= MENU["latte"]["ingredients"]["milk"]:
            resources["milk"] = resources["milk"] - MENU["latte"]["ingredients"]["milk"]
        else:
            return "Sorry there is no enough Milk"

        if resources["coffee"] >= MENU["latte"]["ingredients"]["coffee"]:
            resources["coffee"] = resources["coffee"] - MENU["latte"]["ingredients"]["coffee"]
        else:
            return "Sorry there is no enough coffee"
    elif choice == "cappuccino":
        if resources["water"] >= MENU["cappuccino"]["ingredients"]["water"]:
            resources["water"] = resources["water"] - MENU["cappuccino"]["ingredients"]["water"]
        else:
            return "Sorry there is no enough water"

        if resources["milk"] >= MENU["cappuccino"]["ingredients"]["milk"]:
            resources["milk"] = resources["milk"] - MENU["cappuccino"]["ingredients"]["milk"]
        else:
            return "Sorry there is no enough milk"

        if resources["coffee"] >= MENU["cappuccino"]["ingredients"]["coffee"]:
            resources["coffee"] = resources["coffee"] - MENU["cappuccino"]["ingredients"]["coffee"]
        else:
            return "Sorry there is no enough coffee"






while coffee_machine_on:
    choice = input("What coffee would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino): ")

    if choice == "espresso":
        penny_amnt = int(input("How many pennies?: "))
        nickle_amnt = int(input("How many nickles?: "))
        dime_amnt = int(input("How many dimes?: "))
        quarter_amnt = int(input("How many quarters?: "))

        penny_amnt = float(penny_amnt * penny)
        nickle_amnt = float(nickle_amnt * nickle)
        dime_amnt = float(dime_amnt * dime)
        quarter_amnt = float(quarter_amnt * quarter)

        total_given = penny_amnt + nickle_amnt + dime_amnt + quarter_amnt
        if total_given > espresso_cost:
            total_change = total_given - espresso_cost
            total_change = round(total_change, 2)
            resource_deduction()
            if resource_deduction == "Sorry there is no enough water" or resource_deduction == "Sorry there is no enough milk" or resource_deduction == "Sorry there is no enough coffee":
                print(resource_deduction)
            else:
                print(f"Here is ${total_change} in change")
        else:
            print("Sorry that's not enough money. Money refunded.")

    elif choice == "latte":
        penny_amnt = int(input("How many pennies?: "))
        nickle_amnt = int(input("How many nickles?: "))
        dime_amnt = int(input("How many dimes?: "))
        quarter_amnt = int(input("How many quarters?: "))

        penny_amnt = float(penny_amnt * penny)
        nickle_amnt = float(nickle_amnt * nickle)
        dime_amnt = float(dime_amnt * dime)
        quarter_amnt = float(quarter_amnt * quarter)

        total_given = penny_amnt + nickle_amnt + dime_amnt + quarter_amnt
        if total_given > latte_cost:
            total_change = total_given - latte_cost
            total_change = round(total_change, 2)
            resource_deduction()
            if resource_deduction == "Sorry there is no enough water" or resource_deduction == "Sorry there is no enough milk" or resource_deduction == "Sorry there is no enough coffee":
                print(resource_deduction)
            else:
                print(f"Here is ${total_change} in change")
        else:
            print("Sorry that's not enough money. Money refunded.")

    elif choice == "cappuccino":
        penny_amnt = int(input("How many pennies?: "))
        nickle_amnt = int(input("How many nickles?: "))
        dime_amnt = int(input("How many dimes?: "))
        quarter_amnt = int(input("How many quarters?: "))

        penny_amnt = float(penny_amnt * penny)
        nickle_amnt = float(nickle_amnt * nickle)
        dime_amnt = float(dime_amnt * dime)
        quarter_amnt = float(quarter_amnt * quarter)

        total_given = penny_amnt + nickle_amnt + dime_amnt + quarter_amnt
        if total_given > cappuccino_cost:
            total_change = total_given - cappuccino_cost
            total_change = round(total_change, 2)
            resource_deduction()
            if resource_deduction == "Sorry there is no enough water" or resource_deduction == "Sorry there is no enough milk" or resource_deduction == "Sorry there is no enough coffee":
                print(resource_deduction)
            else:
                print(f"Here is ${total_change} in change")
        else:
            print("Sorry that's not enough money. Money refunded.")

    elif choice == "report":
        print(resources)

    elif choice == "off":
        coffee_machine_on = False
```

And here are the MENU and resources dictionaries:

```
MENU = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "coffee": 18,
        },
        "cost": 1.5,
    },
    "latte": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 200,
            "milk": 150,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 2.5,
    },
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 250,
            "milk": 100,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 3.0,
    }
}

resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
}
```

When I run the code the resource_deduction dictionary doesn't seem to work properly. The while loop doesn't restart when the coffee machine doesn't contain the right amount of resources. It deducts the resources the first time but keeps running even after the resources are not enough. It's probably some dumb mistake, but I can't seem to find where the code is lacking so I need a fresh pair of eyes to look at the code for me. After the problem is solved the code should work the way I intended it to.

Comment: after each statement that you expect to "end" the current run, add a `continue` statement. it will skip the rest of that iteration and move on to the next, effectively "restarting" the loop. be careful though, you might not want to save the resource allocation if the loop restarts.

Comment: also, you are not storing the result of the resource deduction function anywhere. you should assign it to a variable and then compare it -- otherwise, the behavior won't be what you expect. for example, you call the function `resource_deduction()` but you do not assign its return value to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you should store your resource_deduction function result in a variable and pass choice arg to it :

```
rd = resource_deduction(choice)
```

don't forget to add choice in the definition :

```
def resource_deduction(choice): ...
```

then compare rd with your strings:

```
if rd == "Sorry there is no enough water" or rd == "Sorry there is no enough milk" or rd == "Sorry there is no enough coffee"
```

resource_deduction is a function and you should't compare a function with a string

```
resource_deduction=="Sorry there is no enough water" #this is always False
```

Comment: It doesn't really make any sense. I don't really think I need to pass "choice" as a parameter. But I do agree that I needed to pass "resource_deduction" as a variable. Also, I don't really understand what I should put in the if statement "if rd == "Sorry there is no enough water" or rd == "Sorry there is no enough milk" or rd == "Sorry there is no enough coffee". Can you please elaborate on that more?

Comment: @RobertP05 yes you need to pass choice as parameter. In the if statement you compare a function with a string that is wrong , instead you should compare function result (by calling them) with string

Comment: Ok, thank you so much I finally got the code to work, I just need to make small functionality changes but thats all.

Comment: @RobertP05 your welcome, if you find my answer useful, please upvote it